# Transparent backgroud for hover tooltip in bokeh3

Tags: python, bokeh

I am migrating to bokeh 3 (from 2.4.3) trying to reproduce what I had i.e. transparent backgroud and a few customized styles for `bk-tooltip`.

In bokeh 2 I could permanently amend it by using a css file and

```
div.bk-tooltip{
    text-align: center !important;
    font-family: arial !important;
    font-size: 1.15em !important;
    font-weight: 600 !important;
    background-color: transparent !important;
    color: white !important;
    opacity: 1 !important;
    margin: 0px !important;
    border: 0px !important;
    padding: 0px !important;
}
```

In bokeh 3, you can't use that trick anymore.
So I tried that solution: adding style to the html given to the hovertool

```
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, HoverTool
from bokeh.plotting import figure

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=[0,1,2,3,4],y=[1,1,1,1,1]))

p = figure(tools='pan,wheel_zoom,reset')

line = p.line(x='x',y='y', source=source)


hover = HoverTool(tooltips=f"""\

<div style="display: table;">
  <div style="display: table-row;">
    <div style="display: table-cell; text-align:right;">
      x:        
    </div>
    <div style="display: table-cell;text-align:center;">
      @{{y}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<style>
    div.bk-tooltip-content{{
        background-color : transparent;
        color: red;
        margin-top: 0px;
        margin : 0px !important;
        border : 0px important;
        padding : 0px !important;
        }}
</style>
""", renderers=[line])
p.add_tools(hover)

show(p)
```

using `bk-tooltip-content`.
Transparent does not work with/without !important
I can't get to override the default.
I dont think we can use stylesheet for the tooltips of a hovertool (can for a regular tooltip I think but cant find a way of the tooltip of a hover).

Is there another way??

Answer (score 0):

It is still possible to overwrite the css, as you did in your solution. The problem is, that [`.bk-tooltip-content`](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/branch-3.2/bokehjs/src/less/tooltips.less) does not address all the tooltip. There is an underlying visible section.

To set the background transparend, you have to overwrite the  definition of the [`host`](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/branch-3.2/bokehjs/src/less/tooltips.less).

The result of using the lines below instead of your styling gives the figure below.

```
<style>
    :host {{
        background-color : transparent;
        border: 1px dashed red;
        color: red;
    }}
</style>
```

[image]